# Certain Isomorphic Representations of the dihedral group $D_{3}$

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

Using the following presentation of the dihedral group $D_{3}$
\begin{equation}
  D_{3} =
  \left\langle
    r,s
    \mid
    r^{2} = s^{2} = (rs)^{3} = e
  \right\rangle
\end{equation}
There is one (up to isomorphism) irreducible 2-dimensional complex representation
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{matrix}
    \rho : D_{3} \to \operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{C}) \\
    r \mapsto
    \begin{pmatrix}
      0 & 1 \\
      1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix} \\
    s \mapsto
    \begin{pmatrix}
      0 & e^{\frac{-2\pi i}{3}} \\
      e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}} & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{matrix}
\end{equation*}
is there an isomorphic complex irreducible representation to this one such that the entries in the matrices are all in $\mathbb{Z}$?  I think there should be since $D_{3} \cong S_{3}$.

Comment: would you like to see one in $SL_2({\Bbb{Z}}_2)$?

Comment: I commented cuz $\Bbb Z$ hasn't finite subgroups.

Comment: Nitpicking: direct sum of two trivial representations is also two-dimensional, which is inequivalent to $\rho$. You need an extra adjective _irreducible_.

Comment: @Orat I have edited the question to specify that the representations should be simple.  Thanks for your detailed and intuitive answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following assignment:
$$\sigma \colon r \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix},\qquad s \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}.$$
You can check that it is indeed a representation of $D_3$ that is equivalent to $\rho$ by comparing their characters.

**Geometric meaning**. Let $e_1, e_2, e_3$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Take $\alpha = e_1 - e_2, \beta = e_2 - e_3$ and consider $2$-dimensional subspace $V = \operatorname{Span}_\mathbb{R}\{\alpha, \beta\} = \{\, x_1e_1 + x_2e_2 + x_3e_3 \mid x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0 \,\}$. Define a linear transformation $\sigma_\alpha$ on $V$ as a reflection with respect to $\alpha^\perp = \{\, v \in V \mid \langle \alpha, v \rangle = 0 \,\}$:
$$ \sigma_\alpha(v) = v - 2\frac{\langle \alpha, v \rangle}{\langle \alpha, \alpha\rangle}\alpha \qquad (v \in V).$$
The representation matrix of $\sigma_\alpha$ is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}-1 & 0\\ 1 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ as
$$ \sigma_\alpha\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\ \beta\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\ \beta\end{bmatrix}.$$
Similarly, the representation matrix of $\sigma_\beta$ is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & -1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

[image: Root system of type A2]

Basically, they are symmetry of an equilateral triangle which $S_3$ also acts on.

[image: Symmetry of an equilateral triangle]

Comment: For anyone curious about the more general setup where this approach applies, they should look up root systems and Weyl groups (and more generally Coxeter groups and reflection groups).